# Show the $\gcd(\gcd(f_1, f_2), f_3) =1$, where $(f_1,f_2,f_3) = (1)$ or $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ generate the unit ideal.

Tags: polynomials, ideals, gcd-and-lcm

Attempt:

Let $d = \gcd(f_1, f_2)$. Then $(d) = (f_1,f_2)$. So $(d,f_3) = (1)$ => $1 = \gcd(d,f_3)$.

Here I am using the theorem that if $(g) = (f_1,f_2)$, then $g = \gcd(f_1,f_2)$. Is the converse true? If $g = \gcd(f_1,f_2)$ => $(g) = (f_1,f_2)$.

Note (.) is used to denote the ideal generated by $.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. If $g=\gcd(f_1,f_2)$, then $f_1=gh_1$ and $f_2=gh_2$ for some $h_1,h_2$ such that $\gcd(h_1,h_2)=1$. This implies that $f_1,f_2\in (g)$.

We also have $g\in (f_1,f_2)$ since $g=\gcd(f_1,f_2)$ implies $g=Af_1+Bf_2$ for some $A,B$.

Hence $(g)=(f_1,f_2)$.

Comment: Is gcd(h1,h2) =1 relevant here? and is this always true for any two f1, f2/why?

Comment: $\gcd(h_1,h_2)=1$ is not important for the following steps, but it is what is implied by the assumption $g=\gcd(f_1,f_2)$. Yes it is always true for any $f_1,f_2$.

Comment: can you explain more why that is the case?

Comment: The above proof works for general $f_1,f_2$, right?

Comment: I am referring to why you can find such h1, h2 s.t. gcd(h1,h2)=1?

Comment: Oh, I see. Since we assume $g$ is the greatest common divisor of $f_1,f_2$, it is first a common divisor. So $f_1=g\cdot (something)$ where that something is denoted by $h_1$. Similar for $f_2=gh_2$. Now  $g$ is also the greatest, that means $h_1, h_2$ cannot have a common divisor, otherwise $g$ times that divisor will be a common divisor of $f_1, f_2$. Does this make sense?

Comment: I am a little confused. Why doesn't that allow the gcd(h1,h2) <= g where gcd(h1,h2) != 1?

Comment: Let's look at an example. Let $f_1=x^2y, f_2=x^2(y+4)$. Then $g=\gcd(f_1,f_2)=x^2$. We have $f_1=gh_1$ where $h_1=y$ and $f_2=gh_2$, where $h_2=y+4$. So $h_1, h_2$ is the rest of $f_1, f_2$ after you remove the common part of $f_1, f_2$ from them. Hence they cannot have anything in common any more.

Comment: Oh I see now! Thank you!

Comment: ...Glad to help!